# How to set String Array in Java Annotation

Tags: java, annotations

I have declared a annotation like this:

```
public @interface CustomAnnot 
{
    String[] author() default "me";
    String description() default "";
}
```

A valid Annotation therefore would be

```
@CustomAnnot(author="author1", description="test")
```

What I can't figure out is, how to set more than one author, since author() has return String[] this should be possible.

```
@CustomAnnot(author="author1","autor2", description="test")
```

doesn't work!

Comment: `author={"author1","autor2"}`

Answer (score 175, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
public @interface CustomAnnot {

    String[] author() default "me";
    String description() default "";

}
```

And your annotation:

```
    @CustomAnnot(author={"author1","author2"}, description="test")
```

Comment: How can I read that value at runtime. I need to get all the value of author