# Java - int array in custom annotations

Tags: java

Is this possible to get an int array in a custom annotation?

If yes, how to I call it?

Here's a dummy example to help me understand... Suppose that I have @Add() that takes an infinite number of operand.

@Add(operand1=10, operand2=20, operandx=...)

What I want is to have only one property operands.

Comment: [Does this answer help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20632992/577417)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve what you want if you add a parameter to the interface as an array.

```
public @interface Add {
     int [] operands(); 
}
```

Then usage would be :

```
@Add(operands={1,2,3})
```

**Note:** var-args would not work; the compiler will reject it.