# What can be real case use of Repeating annotations?

Tags: java, java-8

Actually, I am going through new things in Java 8. There are many new stuff has come i.e Lambda expressions , Default methods and so many..

One of the feature is Repeating Annotations,

> " Repeating Annotations provide the ability to apply the same annotation type more than once to the same declaration or type use "

Here I can Understand that I can use same Annotation many times.

I am trying understand real / practical usage of this addition. and trying to understand why they missed it until java 7.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have, for example, some role-based security, you'd be able to write something like:

```
@Authorize(role="USER")
@Authorize(role="ADMIN")
public void doStuff(){
...codez
}
```

In previous Java versions, to achieve the same, you'd have to do something like:

```
@Authorize(roles={"USER", "ADMIN"})
public void doStuff(){
...codez
}
```

or

```
@Authorize(role="USER, ADMIN")
public void doStuff(){
..moar codez
}
```

The difference, as you can see for yourself, is minimal, and the @Repeatable annotation is more syntactic sugar than a huge breakthrough. The benefit is not obvious unless you consider some more verbose annotations, say bunch of Quartz cron expressions. Prior java 8, you'd have to do something like:

```
@Cron(values={"* * * * * 10", "12 * * * * 0", "4 * 5 * 6 * 7"})
public void doCron(){

}
```

But in java 8 you could have a separate cron at each line, which makes the expression more readable.

Comment: We can also write these as 
      @Authorize(roles="ADMIN , User")
       public void doStuff(){
        ...codez
       }

Comment: We can write everything in more than one way. Java 8 just added a new way of writing it. Imagine if instead of roles, you had a bunch of quartz cron expressions. It would be nicer if each was on a separate lines. But once again, what Repeatable adds to java8, is more a syntactic sugar than something to ponder on from design perspective.

Answer (score 6):

It is much helpful when you have multiple fields declared in an annotation. For example:

```
@Repeatable
public @interface Role {
   String type;
   String[] allowed;
}
```

In this case, it is much easier to use this kind of annotation for multiple roles:

```
@Role(type="readonly", allowed={"view"})
@Role(type="admin", allowed={"view,add,update,delete"})
public boolean checkAllowed() {
}
```

Comment: This is not correct, you cannot define `@Repeatable` without a wrapping class as value to it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is the obvious: You want to annotate something with multiple values.

Prior to this feature you'd need to parse the single allowed argument in your annotation processing code:

```
@SomeAnnotation(value="this,that")
String foo;
```

Or (from comments):

```
@SomeAnnotation(value={"author1","author2"})
String foo;
```

The annotation processing code would need to have logic to deal with splitting the value and dealing with it, or getting multiple values. Allowing multiple annotations makes this simpler from a logic perspective. It's just a *convenience* feature.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632940/how-to-set-string-array-in-java-annotation

Comment: @baba Same deal. It's simpler code to process multiple annotations of the same type. I edited to make more clear this is simply a convenience feature.