# Annotation parameter - String[] type parameter set to string literal

Tags: java, annotations, variadic-functions

Read about [How to set String Array in Java Annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632940/how-to-set-string-array-in-java-annotation)

I have a query, for below code:

```
@Unfinished("Just articleware")
public @interface Unfinished {
    public enum Priority {LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH}
    String value();
    String[] owners() default "";
    Priority priority() default Priority.MEDIUM;
}
```

Expecting a syntax `String[] owners() default {}`. How Java compiler allow string literal syntax(`""`) for `String[]` type parameter(`owners`)?

Comment: Both versions are acceptable. `default ""` is like `default {""}` so default value is array with *one* element: empty string. If you set `default {}` then default value is *empty* array.

Comment: The array with an empty string. You can also put a single string "default" in there as well or `{}` simply for an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

As marked in the comments as well, the default value `""` for the annotation key `owners` creates an array with an element that's an empty string. You can also put a single string `"default"` in there as well which would lead to creating an array with only value "default"

OR

`{}` simply for an empty array if the need be.

---

To test this you can mark the annotation with Runtime retention policy as :

```
@Unfinished("Just articleware")
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) // mark with Runtime retention policy
public @interface Unfinished {
    enum Priority {LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH}

    String value();

    String[] owners() default "";

    Priority priority() default Priority.MEDIUM;
}
```

Annotate a class with this

```
@Unfinished(value = "")
public class AnnotatedClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

and then use Reflection to get the values of the keys of `Unfinished` as :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Testing...");
    Class<AnnotatedClass> obj = AnnotatedClass.class;
    if (obj.isAnnotationPresent(Unfinished.class)) {
        Annotation annotation = obj.getAnnotation(Unfinished.class);
        Unfinished unfinished = (Unfinished) annotation;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(unfinished.owners()));
    }
}
```