# What are these curly braces doing in this SpringBoot annotation?

Tags: java

I am somewhat new to Java and know almost nothing about Spring / SpringBoot. I saw this line of code today:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {TestRepositoryConfig.class})
```

I am not really clear what's happening here. From my existing knowledge I infer that I'm looking at something like a key-value parameter, where `classes` is a parameter passed to the constructor or function called `SpringBootTest`, and its value is `{TestRepositoryConfig.class}`.

But I have no idea what those curly braces are doing. Why are they needed? And how could I have answered this question for myself? I didn't know what to search for. "Curly braces java annotation" gave me a deluge of results without any clear answers, unless I wanted to commit to extended reading.

Comment: Maybe this will help clear it up: [How to set String Array in Java Annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632940/how-to-set-string-array-in-java-annotation)

Comment: Note that when this is used in cases less closed-ended than `@SpringBootTest`, it's commonly recommended to put the values on separate lines and include a trailing comma to reduce commit noise when values are added or removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means you can supply multiple values as an array:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {TestRepositoryConfig.class, Class2.class, Class3.class})
```

Think of it as the same syntax as for initializing an array:

```
String[] array = { "one", "two", "three" };
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a syntax construction to add a few parameters, like:

```
classes = {TestRepositoryConfig.class, Another.class...}
```